# Upvotes without adding reputation

Tags: support, reputation, upvotes

I provided an answer and now it has 2 upvotes. But it only gave me 11 points. In my reputation, it shows as two events: both as an upvote with 10 points and another one with 1. Why did I receive only 1 point for other upvote?

Now it has 5 upvotes but the reputation being adding is still 11. It's not adding any for other 3 upvotes. Why?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 11):

You have received your maximum of 200 points from votes today, and have hit the reputation cap. Congratulations!

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given day. Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately [...]. Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.

The +1 was a result of you having lost 1 point earlier in the day because you downvoted an answer; if you do so again *and* receive another upvote on a question or answer you'll receive another +1 to bring you back to +200 reputation.

Note that any bounties or answer accepts are counted separately; if you are awarded another accept today, you'll get the +15 beyond the cap.

The cap exists to stop people from earning privileges too rapidly and to give everyone a fairer chance to keep up with the top scorers. We don't want someone to gain all their reputation from a popular answer in a single day, for example.

Comment: By the way, if that's the first time, one even gets a bronze badge. And for doing it 150 times, you get a shiny golden "legendary" badge.

Comment: @Vogel612: You also get it the Mortarboard for reaching 200 points *overall*, including accepts. And you earn the golden Legendary badge for doing this 150 times, not 200.

Comment: @MartijnPieters why reputation score not increasing? Now my daily reputation is `215` it is not increasing for current upvotes. I already got Mortarboard while ago.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera: Because you are capped. You cannot earn more than 200 points from upvotes and suggested edits in a day.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera: the badge is just to teach you that hitting 200 points is something special and worthy of celebration; it doesn't mean you will be exempt from the cap. :-)