# I didn't get 200 reputation points for the day, but still question shown upvoted but reputation is not added!

Tags: support, reputation, upvotes, specific-answer

I don't know it's a **bug** or what, but I have seen this on my reputation tab.

One of my questions was up-voted yesterday (as shown on the below image),
but the reputation points aren't mentioned there.

[image: Reputation points issue]

I have read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268733/upvotes-without-adding-reputation) in which the **OP** faced the same issue, but in that case he had already received **200 reputation points** for the day, but that's **not in my case**.

Comment: Your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18240509) is a Community Wiki post, which do not earn reputation from votes. It was made CW because the *question* is a CW post.

Comment: Yes You are right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18240509) is a [Community Wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), which do not earn reputation from votes. It was made CW because the question is a CW post.

The question was automatically made CW because it was edited more than 10 times by the OP, a feature that [has since been removed altogether](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits).